# C Tokenize String

Tags: c++, c, arrays, regex, string

Im trying to tokenize a string by delimiters while keeping the delimiters. I tried using `strtok(string, delimiters)` but that function doesn't keep the delimiters.  For example, if my string is:

```
"my name < is|John >hi"
```

I want to split when I see the symbols `"space", "<", ">"`.

The tokens would be:

```
my, space, name, space, < , space, is, |, John, space, <, hi
```

At first, I tried to read char by char until I saw a delimiter symbol.  If I didnt see a symbol, I would append the read char to the string before it. For example, for the string "hi|bye". I would read the "h", read next char.  Its a "i" so append it to the "h". Read next symbol, its a delimiter so put "hi" into an array and also the "|" into an array. Repeat until done.  I ran into issues doing this.

Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
int main()
{
  char *line = "command1 | command2 command3 > command4 < command5";
  do_tokenize(line);
  return 0;
}
void do_tokenize(char *line)
{
  char *tokenized[100];
  char token[100];
  int tokenCounter = 0;
  int tokenLength = 0;
  int i;
  int newToken = 1;
  int tokenNum = 0;
  for(i=0; line[i] !='\0'; i++)
    {
      if(line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '<' && line[i] != '>' && line[i] != '|')
    {
      token[tokenLength] = line[i];
      tokenLength++;
      newToken = 1;
    }
      else
    {
      if(newToken == 1)
        {
          token[tokenLength] = '\0';
          tokenized[tokenNum] = token;
          tokenLength = 0;
          tokenNum++;
          newToken = 0;

          token[tokenLength] = line[i];
          token[tokenLength+1] = '\0';
          tokenized[tokenNum] = token;
          tokenLength = 0;
          tokenNum++;
        } 
      else
        {
          token[tokenLength] = line[i];
          token[tokenLength+1] = '\0';
          tokenized[tokenNum] = token;
          tokenLength = 0;
          tokenNum++;
          newToken = 0;
        }
    }//end else
    }//end for

  token[tokenLength] = '\0';
  tokenized[tokenNum] = token;
  tokenNum++;

  //print is saying that all of tokenized[j] is the last token ie command5
  int j=0;
  for(j; j<tokenNum; j++)
    printf("%s\n", tokenized[j]);

}
```

When I try to print out the entire array (tokenized[j]), its saying that all of it is just the last token, `"command5"`. This is done in `C`.

Comment: All elements of your `tokenized` point to the same address, i.e. `token`, which means you are using the same buffer again and again, that is why all you got when you print `tokenized` is the last token.

Comment: But my elements are in `tokenized[tokenNum]` and I am incrementing `tokenNum` after I add something to the array. And `token` is being rewritten after I find that its a token. I put print statements to check that the token is correct also.

Comment: Every `tokenized[tokenNum]` equals `token`, and you rewrite the contents of `token` every time, that is the problem. Try to print the value (as an address) of `tokenized[tokenNum]` when you iterate through that `for` loop.

Comment: How is this different from:  `int x=5; int y=x; x=3; int z=x` .  Aren't `y` and `z` both pointing to `x`? Im not sure how to remedy this problem.  Should I be initializing a new `token` after I have found a token?

Comment: That is the difference between variable and address: copy a variable you get the contents (i.e. value) of that variable; copy an address, you only get that address, not the contents that address addressed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you would like to have elements of the tokenized array point to each token found in 'line'.  The code faithfully copies each character of a token to the char array 'token'.  After the entire token is loaded into 'token' it is zero terminated.

```
-
```

All of this is good; however the next step seems to be where the code flawed.  The next ponter in the tokenized array is then set to point at 'token'.  The problem is that 'token' is your working storage, and the content of 'token' is re-build for each new token.

```
-
```

At the end, all the affected pointers in the 'tokenize" array point to the same place; specifically, they all point to 'token'.  Of course, the content of 'token' is the last parsed token.

```
-
```

Hence, when printing out the 'tokenize' array, and being that they all point to 'token', and being that the content of token is the last parsed token ("Command5")...

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great program to run in a debugger to understand what it does and how it goes wrong.

If you are using some sort of IDE (integrated development environment), probably all you have to do is press the "step into" button.

If you are using gcc, then you can easily use gdb by adding `-g` to the gcc command:

```
$ gcc -g myprog.c -o myprog
$ gdb myprog
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4009d1
Starting program: myprog 

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004009d1 in main ()
(gdb) step
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you guys for editing my question to be correct. I removed my debugging "printf" statements to make the code clearer for you guys. After I put the token into tokenized[tokenNum], I print out tokenized[tokenNum] and they are all correct. For some reason, its overriding my tokenizing array somewhere but tokenNum is only incremented not decremented so how can tokenized[0] be the last token in my string for example. All of tokenized[] is "command5". Im using gcc and never used gdb before.